# Oracle OpenSSO Fedlet .NET Home Folder could not be found

Tags: .net, oracle, opensso

I am trying to use the Oracle Open SSO Fedlet, I have successfully connected to the IDP using the sample app supplied with the fedlet, but then when I drop the dll in the bin dir of my app and add the config files to the App_Data directory and try and visit the application I get the error message

> Specified home folder could not be found

As far as i understand the default home folder should be App_Data but this exists and this is where I have put my config files.
any ideas anyone?

Comment: The quick fix will be `serviceProviderUtility = new ServiceProviderUtility(Context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));`

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when you place the web pages into any folder apart from the root.  You can then get it to work by placing an App_Data folder into that folder.

So Example, if you create a folder call Pages, and place your web pages in there, then create another folder called Pages\App_Data and place all the files that are in the current projects App_Data folder into the new folder and things will work again